# Separate site module to another git project

Tags: git

I have a Zend Framework site with the following structure:

- application

  - controllers
  - forms
  - modules

    - separateMeModule
    - api
  - ...
- data
- docs
- library
- public
- ...

For version control we use git. Currently we have 2 branches - master and development.

What I would like to do is to separate module "separateMeModule" into another project (and create separate git repository for it) and remove it from the original one. But I would like to save these 2 branches (with all changes history) in the new separated project. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `git subtree split` command to isolate the history of a particular directory in your repository.  For example, if you were to run:

```
git subtree split --prefix modules/separateModule -b separateModule
```

This would create a new branch `separateModule` containing only the history of that repository.  You would then be able to push this into a dedicated repository.  For example, create a new repository:

```
git init --bare /path/to/separateModule.git
```

And push the new `separateModule` branch to the `master` branch of the new repository:

```
git checkout separateModule
git push /path/to/separateModule.git separateModule:master
```

Note that at no point have we modified the history of your existing repository, and you can safely remove the branch we created with `git subtree split`:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D separateModule
```